# What is basepath() in slim twig extension

Tags: php, twig, slim

What does the `$basepath` refers in twig extension and `str_replace` function is used here

```
    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace('index.php', '', $container->get('request')->getUri()->getBasePath()), '/');
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension($container->get('router'), $basePath));

    return $view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Twig extension adds some useful twig functions (see [github](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/blob/master/src/TwigExtension.php#L34)), it depends on Base Path parameter.

> **Base Path**
>
> If your Slim application's front-controller lives in a physical subdirectory beneath your document root directory, you can fetch the HTTP request's physical base path (relative to the document root) with the Uri object's getBasePath() method. This will be an empty string if the Slim application is installed in the document root's top-most directory.

See [slim framework docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html)

`str_ireplace()` is used to just remove `index.php`

Comment: What will be the base path in twig if working on localhost. Is ithe path to twig template or a reference to domain or something else can you give a example

Comment: It depends on where your front controller physically located relatively to servers document root. [Here](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Uri.php#L207) is how it formed. If you are interested in specific example, you can test it by yourself by putting something like `var_dump($container->get('request')->getUri()->getBasePath());die();`. In most cases it is just empty string, since usually your document root is pointed straight to front controller `public/index.php`.